# Deaktivate Rigid Body Object after a certaine timeframe

Tags: rigidbody

due to the jittering of Mesh Collision Shape - I would like to deactivate Rigid Body objects e.g. after a certain timeframe.

In blender2.79 I found this Python API for making an object with a certain name a passive object:

bpy.data.objects['name'].rigid_body(type='PASSIVE')

However, this results in the following error: 'RigidBodyObject' object is not callable

Any help on how to attribute "PASSIVE" to an rigid_body object of a certain name as Python API for blender2.79 would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

```
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].rigid_body.type = 'ACTIVE'
```

This is how you do it. If someone can explain further why I'd be happy to read it :)